# How to put_parameter where value is type file using boto3?

Tags: boto3, aws-ssm

Using the aws-cli, I can do this:

`aws ssm put-parameter --name my-param --value file://my-file.txt --type String`

How can I do the same in boto3 where the value is of type file?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm/client/put_parameter.html), the 'Value' option is of string type. Therefore, your requirement for the 'Value' to be of file type is not valid. You should use Python code to read a file, store its content in a variable, and then pass that variable to the 'ssm put_parameter' function in the boto3 library. The sample code below:

```
import boto3

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

# Read a file
file_path = 'my-file.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    file_content = file.read()

# Put parameter to SSM Parameter Store
parameter_name = 'my-param'
parameter_value = file_content
parameter_type = 'String'

response = ssm_client.put_parameter(
    Name=parameter_name,
    Value=parameter_value,
    Type=parameter_type
)
```

Comment: I was looking for an equivalent (something maybe built-in to boto3 if value starts with "file://" that means it's using file protocol and therefore load content of file). `file://` itself in aws cli cannot find a documentation so maybe boto3 has something similar.

Comment: The syntax 'file://' is commonly used across AWS CLI commands. So you may not find it explicitly mentioned in individual documentation. For more information, you can refer to the following [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html#cli-usage-parameters-file-how)